# How to do proper validation for array of objects ids in nodeJS rest api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, joi

I am currently struggling to implement rest api build in nodeJS, mongoDB, express. One of fields takes array of objects ids (field sprints in model project). The question is how to do proper validation in route file (projects.js) when doing post method (keeping in mind that field sprints is not required)?

I was trying to check **typeof req.body.sprints** and also to do **lenght** on this, but with no result. I was also trying to find answer on stackoverflow etc., but didn't came across nothing similar.

*project.js (model file)*

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Project = mongoose.model(
    "Project",
    new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
...
        sprints: [
            {
                type: new mongoose.Schema({
                    name: {
                        type: String,
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5,
                        maxlength: 255
                    },
                    isClosed: { type: Boolean, default: false }
                })
            }
        ]
    })
);

function validateProject(project) {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string()
            .min(5)
            .max(255)
            .required(),
        createdBy: Joi.objectId().required(),
        isClosed: Joi.boolean(),
        sprints: Joi.array().items(Joi.objectId())
    };

    return Joi.validate(project, schema);
}

exports.Project = Project;
exports.validate = validateProject;
```

*projects.js (route file)*

```
const express = require("express");
const { User } = require("../models/user");
const { Sprint } = require("../models/sprint");
const { Project, validate } = require("../models/project");
const router = express.Router();

...

/* POST project */
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const { error } = validate(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    const user = await User.findById(req.body.createdBy);
    if (!user) return res.status(400).send("Invalid user");

    const sprint = await Sprint.findById(req.body.sprints);
    if (!sprint) return res.status(400).send("Invalid sprint");
    //i think that here i have to validate if sprint has even one 
    element and only then do object id validation

    const project = new Project({
        name: req.body.name,
        createDate: req.body.createDate,
        createdBy: { _id: user._id, name: user.name },
        isClosed: req.body.isClosed,
        sprints: [
            {
                _id: sprint._id,
                name: sprint.name,
                isClosed: sprint.isClosed
            }
        ]
    });
    await project.save();

    res.send(project);
});

...

module.exports = router;
```

In my post method i am checking if given id exist in table Sprints but i have problem if no sprint id is provided (i get 'Invalid sprint' message). Expected result will be: i can provide array of sprints, one sprint, or none at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out

```
function validateProject(project) {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string()
            .min(5)
            .max(255)
            .required(),
        createdBy: Joi.objectId().required(),
        isClosed: Joi.boolean(),
        sprints:Joi.array().items(
                Joi.object({
                    name: Joi.string(),
                    isClosed: Joi.boolean
                })
            )
        })
    };

    return Joi.validate(project, schema);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this should work. I've just left it as is and handled it in a frontend part of app, but it is good to know that it can be done.